# How to translate postman curl code into filemaker pro through "Insert from URL" curl options?

Tags: postman, filemaker

I was trying to transfer a working curl code in postman to filemaker, however I couldn't make it work.

The following is the working curl code from postman:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://apidev.nationex.com/api/ShippingV2/GetDestinationETA?ShippingID=606200005' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: apidev.nationex.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e9f8cf52-fbe4-4a74-8b49-d03b54c238d6,912db917-0a65-4644-9526-68a062f71e70' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 83' \
  -d '{
    "CustomerID":162450,
    "DestPostalCode":"J3Y5T7",
    "PickupDate":"2019-04-29",
}
    '
```

The following is the code I put into filemaker curl options:

```
"-X POST \
  'https://apidev.nationex.com/api/ShippingV2/GetDestinationETA?ShippingID=606200005' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: apidev.nationex.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e9f8cf52-fbe4-4a74-8b49-d03b54c238d6,07e38ca7-19a1-49ab-a57d-11c62c398b06' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 83' \
  -d '{
    \"CustomerID\":162450,
    \"DestPostalCode\":\"J3Y5T7\",
    \"PickupDate\":\"2019-04-29\",
}
    '"
```

The following is the error message I received in Filemaker:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at Nat.Dal.DAL.DALWebApiUser.IsTokenValid(HttpRequestMessage _request, Int32 _customerID) in C:\\GIT\\nat.dal\\DAL\\DALWebApiUser.cs:line 257\r\n   at NationexWebApi.Controllers.ShippingV2Controller.GetDestinationETA(DTOETARequest _request) in C:
```

Could anybody show me some insights here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is from the API, not from FileMaker.

You don't specify the URL in cURL options, only the additional arguments.

You probably want `--show-error` as an option.

Differences you should know about in the way FileMaker cURL works: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/curl-options.html

Also, you don't need to escape newlines, but you may want to mixing quote styles between single and double quotes.

Maybe something like this (times out when I try it, though)

```
"-H \"Accept: */*\" 
-H \"Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\" 
-H \"Cache-Control: no-cache\" 
-H \"Connection: keep-alive\" 
-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" 
-H \"Host: apidev.nationex.com\" 
-H \"Postman-Token: e9f8cf52-fbe4-4a74-8b49-d03b54c238d6,07e38ca7-19a1-49ab-a57d-11c62c398b06\" 
-H \"User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0\" 
-H \"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate\" 
-H \"cache-control: no-cache\" 
-H \"content-length: 83\" 
-d \"{
    \"CustomerID\":162450,
    \"DestPostalCode\":\"J3Y5T7\",
    \"PickupDate\":\"2019-04-29\",
}\""
```

It's possible that the API site is just broken. Try setting up your own web service in which you can inspect incoming requests, or use httpProxy to examine the requests.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your reply, Sam!  There's no problem with the API site, because it works fine in Postman. I changed my CURL options to be like this now:    "-H \"Accept: */*\" -H \"Authorization: XXXXXXXX\" -H \"Cache-Control: no-cache\" -H \"Connection: keep-alive\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"cache-control: no-cache\" --ignore-content-length -d $josn --show-error"   But it still won't work. It keeps transferring URL data, but won't load any data, no error showing either. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Try setting up https://www.wireshark.org/#download as a proxy. Point the URL to your WireShark instance, then try submitting from Postman and FileMaker, and spot the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Generator](https://www.geistinteractive.com/products/generator/) from Geist Interactive instead of Postman. You can simply copy paste the FileMaker code.

Comment: Thanks Siva, Generator is really a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to build the connection with Nationex API. Here's what the working cURL options looks like in Filemaker pro:

"-H \"Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d @$josn "

Thank everyone for the help!